# How to store my session array into my database

Tags: php, html, mysql

How do I store my data in session array into my database ? Upon entering the product and its quantity, the user will be directed to a checkout page. In the checkout page, upon filling up the necessary information in a form, I am trying to use a button to submit the session array into my database.

My current code:

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    $array = $_SESSION['shopping_cart'];  
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'table');
    ?>
    $sql = "INSERT INTO customer_order (productName, quantity, totalPrice, pax)";
    foreach($array as $product){
       $sql = "INSERT INTO p2_5.customer_order (productName, quantity, totalPrice, pax)";
       $sql .= " VALUES ('{$product['name']}', '{$product['quantity']}', '{$product['price']}', '{$product['pax']}')";
       if ($connect->query($sql)) {
          $errorMsg = "Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error;
          $success = false;
   } 
}
```

However, upon clicking on the button, I am able to store client information into my database, but I would have an PHP error message Undefined index: name, Undefined index: quantity, Undefined index: price, Undefined index: pax ?

[image]

Comment: Can do it a a JSON String `json_encode()` or using `serialize()`

Comment: 1) you're closing php tag with `?>`. 2) you're passing elements from `$array` without referencing to their `index`, I mean without `$array[0]` or `$array[1]`

Comment: What order information are you missing?

Comment: _“What did I do wrong ?”_ - looks like you are developing without having proper PHP error reporting enabled, otherwise PHP should have given you notices about how you are trying to access array elements that aren’t actually there. So please go and enable it first of all now!

Comment: Oh I see now. You need to add a loop to your code. Looping over the `$array`

Comment: And of course as that means you will be adding multiple rows to this table, you will have to also create a new column in this table to hold a link to this User, so you can find the right rows later

Comment: @04FS okay, so I receive an undefined index error. If i were to store the product info into my database on the product page itself, I am able to do so without error, but when I tried to store it when I am on the checkoutpage and I call my session array,I have the undefined index error ?

Comment: Well then you are obviously dealing with different data structures in both places. On your product page, you appear to have an array that contains `name`, `quantity` etc. directly on the top level, whereas in your session you have an array _of_ such arrays.

Comment: the data structures is the same. I have check the data structure on my cart page and the checkout page. They are the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing elements from `$array` without referencing to their `indexes`, I mean without `$array[0]` or `$array[1]`.

You need to add a loop like below:

```
foreach($array as $product){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO customer_order (productName, quantity, totalPrice, pax)";
   $sql .= " VALUES ('{$product['name']}', '{$product['quantity']}', '{$product['price']}', '{$product['pax']}')";
   if ($connect->query($sql)) {
       $errorMsg = "Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error;
       $success = false;
   } 
   if ($errorMsg != "Connection failed: ") {echo $errorMsg; $connect->close(); return;}
}
```

This will allow you to save each row data from `shopping_cart`.

Comment: sorry, however when I check my database, nothing is being stored

Comment: @JohnWick, show me `echo $sql; return;`. Put it before `if` statement. This will make the first query string and you'll see what you're sending to DB.

Comment: INSERT INTO root.customer_order (productName, quantity, totalPrice, pax) VALUES ('Seafood Set', '8', '250', '90')

Comment: @JohnWick, try to erase `p2_5.`(or `root.`) and try again

Comment: @JohnWick, hah, then add `'` around each column name -> `('productName', 'quantity', 'totalPrice', 'pax')`

Comment: @JohnWick, are you getting any errors during inserting?

Comment: Nope it is still empty, no I am not getting any errors message

Comment: @JohnWick, I've updated my answer according to our final solution. If it's not so hard for you, please, accept the answer. Thanks in advance